# powershell replace xml element contains special characters

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to remove the whole xml element `<ElementOne>Some Value;Value</ElementOne>` from the read file in a batch file:

```
set toReplace='"<ElementOne>Some Value;Value</ElementOne>"'
set replaced=''
powershell -NoProfile -Command "(gc %file%) -replace %toReplace%, %replaced% | Out-File %file% -encoding ascii
```

If I use the back slashes for the specials characters e.g. `"\<ElementOne\>Some Value\;Value\<\/ElementOne\>"` still the element is not removed. What could be my mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
set toReplace='"<ElementOne>Some Value;Value</ElementOne>"'
```

with:

```
set "toReplace='<ElementOne>Some Value;Value</ElementOne>'"
```

That is, by **enclosing the variable name, the `=` char., and the variable value in `"..."` *overall***, you're free to use metacharacters such as `<` and `>` in the value, and the `"` chars. then only have *syntactic* function, i.e. they do not become *part of the value*, as they do in your attempt (which is what caused your problem).